# Can you create sql files in Visual Studio to default without the BOM?

Tags: visual-studio-2019

When I create a new sql file in Visual Studio I get the encoding: `UTF-8 with BOM` by default.

I'm wondering if the default behavior can be changed in Visual Studio to create files without the BOM.

Answer (score 0):

The template file for sql used in Visual Studio 2019 Community is stored here:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\Common7\IDE\NewFileItems\NewFile_SqlServerDeveloperTools.sql`

Save this file without the BOM and new sql files will be created without the BOM.